# is there a local DNS Software which uses external DNS for actual resolution?

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, local-area-network

I have a LAN with few PCs on it. I want to have them to use a local server for DNS look up, and let the local server do look up with external (actual) DNS.

So, which proxy-DNS server do you suggest me? (one that is small, easy to set-up and handle).

**I am running on Ubuntu by the way.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Dnsmasq, Bind, and most other DNS daemons do this out of the box.  For a small setup on Ubuntu Dnsmasq will probably be easiest.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq

Answer (score 3):

There is DNS forwarding option in every DNS server. You can utilize that feature for your need.